# pyenv (for Windows) installs pytest.exe in its own location when a virtual environment has been activated

Tags: python, windows-10, pytest, pyenv, virtual-environment

I installed [pyenv for Windows](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) a couple of weeks ago. I understood the business of "global"/"local" versions of Python. Global version is 3.10.5.

Today I set up a VE (virtual environment) in a different location.

With this VE activated, I installed pytest:

```
(doc_indexer_ve) D:\...\doc_indexer> pip install pytest
```

To my surprise, I then found that pytest.exe had been installed not in the VE location, but under the pyenv location (under Scripts). Not only that, but to my horror (yes I exaggerate), when I deactivated the VE I found that pytest ran in the plain vanilla 3.10.5 (i.e. the pyenv global version).

I then went and checked on previous VEs which I had installed, prior to my installing pyenv: the pytest.exe file is located in the Scripts\ dir of such VE installations.

What is happening with the new VE seems very anomalous to me. I want pytest to be a component of my VE, not of the underlying bare-metal Python setup.

I thought it might be possible to just move the two files under the pyenv installation, i.e. pytest.exe and py.test.exe, to the Scripts\ dir of this new VE. No good:

```
(doc_indexer_ve) D:\...\doc_indexer>pytest
'pytest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I then looked at PATH while still in the VE. Right at the top of the list is the VE's Scripts\ dir where I have copied pytest.exe:

```
(doc_indexer_ve) D:\...\doc_indexer>path
PATH=D:\apps\Python\virtual_envs\doc_indexer_ve\Scripts;D:\apps\java\jdk-11.0.6_UsedByW10\bin; ...
```

Now I do experience something akin to horror. What is pyenv doing to my system exactly? I'm thinking of uninstalling it now and reverting to my plain-old-OS version of Python.

Does anyone know how I can install pytest.exe as part of the VE, not the pyenv Python installation?

***Later***
Now I find that when I do `pip install PyQt5-sip` in the VE, this **also** gets installed under the pyenv Python installation (Lib\site-packages), not in the VE location. Maybe I've misunderstood something about pyenv. I thought the idea was that, as with my plain-old-OS Python installation, the whole point of a VE is to be a completely independent superstructure grafted **on top** of it, so you can happily swap in and swap out VEs at will.

Perhaps the Linux version of pyenv behaves more in line with what I'm expecting? Have Linux OSs available but not yet got around to making experiments...

***Footnote on reverting***
I removed the pyenv entries in PATH (so that my plain-old-OS Python would again become the underlying Python installation) and rebooted.
I went into the new VE and tried `pip install pytest`. Oh dear: pytest.exe now installed under the plain-old-OS Python Scripts\ directory, not under the VE!
I found that this VE which had been set up when pyenv was in charge was in some way "tainted".
When I deleted it and recreated it using my plain-old-OS Python everything worked as before: pytest.exe and PyQt5-sip installed **in the VE** under Scripts\ or site-packages\ respectively, etc. Thank God for that. Maybe pyenv (in its W10 incarnation at least) is too clever for its own good.